# Scala Spark Job is not getting failed even date format changed in Source File

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I'm very new to this Website even for Spark. Please help me.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("dateFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy").load("file:///home/cloudera/data/zeyodataa.txt")
                     
val df1=df.write.format("csv").option("dateFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy").mode("overwrite").save("/user/cloudera/surendar")
```

Comment: What is the issue. Post your source data and show us the output and your expected output

Comment: Thank you very much for your response....!!!!

Below data is source data
------------------------------------
name,amount,product,Date
Sai,5,cookies,10-23-2022
Zeyo,6,Fevi,10-23-2022
Sai,5,choco,10-23-2022
Zeyo,6,butter,10-23-2022
_____________
In future if date format is mismatch like yyyy-MM-dd or  dd-yyyy-MM.
My job is not failed. Even its updating wrong format date in target directory.

Comment: My expect output is Job get fail when wrong date format has uploaded in source file.

Comment: Dear All, Need extra column with value pass or fail if date format expected value is pass otherwise fail. how to apply condition ?
@Roshan Bro Please help me if you know..